# build setting of optimization level in released iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

My iPhone app submitted Apple review has been rejected lots of time because of some issue.

When I tested it with my iPhone, nothing was issue. but apple reviewer found some bugs.

I knew when I wanna test in the released app, I should change Build configuration in Edit scheme "Debug" to "Release" and I realized why my app behavior is difference between debug and release is the build setting of optimization level.

In the build setting, optimization level of Debug is "None[-O0]" and optimization level of Release is "Fastest,Smallest[-Os]". After I change optimization level of Release "Fastest,Smallest[-Os]" to "None[-O0]", I thought some issue are resolved.

Finally I would like to ask this question. would something be happened if I submitted my iPhone app to Apple with optimization level of Release "None[-O0]"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The app would likely run slower than it did before, and be bigger.

You should probably fix the bugs, instead of hoping that they just don't show up anymore. Try things like the Static Analyzer (Build -> Analyze in Xcode) to find the problems.

If you need to, you can ask the App Reviewers for more details, and they'll be happy to give you steps to reproduce, crashlogs, etc.

Comment: I asked ITS and got a answer like follow:From an App Review perspective, you can use whatever optimization level you
prefer.